# Using Neorouter Free

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc

I want to try out Neorouter as an alternative for Teamviewer or Logmein.

I've installed the server on my Ubuntu desktop, opened a Windows VM, installed the client, and I can login to the server. I downloaded the Ubuntu client, installed it on the same server and can login via commandline.

Now I'm stuck. How do I proceed, add computers to the network, use remote desktop or VNC?! Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places, but I can't find a proper manual.

Comment: Teamviewer is currently free with no annouced plans to end its free service.

Comment: I want to figure out how Neorouter works anyway.

Comment: Have you read the contents of this page? http://www.neorouter.com/Documents.html

Comment: Totally overlooked that page! I guess that's what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Page 2 of the online manual,  [here](http://download.neorouter.com/Documents/nr_howitworks_en.pdf)

> Users can access a NeoRouter domain using the Network Explorer. After signing in with domain name and credential, you will see a list of computers in the domain. If you click on a computer, the launch pad dialog will pop up and it allows you to launch add-on applications and control the target computer remotely.
>
> NeoRouter also provides a portable Network Explorer that you can run from a USB drive without installation. This feature is especially useful if you are using a computer that you do not have the privileges to setup new software, e.g. in a library or hotel.

There is also a good list of very informative screenshots, [here](http://www.neorouter.com/Screenshots.html).